Docker mail server suddenly stopped receiving mails - Sender address rejected: Domain not found
I run a mail server on a small VPS running docker-mail-server.
It was working perfectly fine until 2024-10-02, where it started rejecting email.
I renewed the certificates, even though they expired on 2024-10-15 (two weeks after it stopped working).
Whenever I receive an email, the following trace appears in the log (here an email sent from my protonmail address):
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[185.70.43.21]: 450 4.1.8 <$MY_ADDRESS@protonmail.com>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found; from=<$MY_ADDRESS@protonmail.com> to=<contact@$MY_DOMAIN> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-4321.protonmail.ch>
Interpreting that as "I don't know what that domain is so I reject the email", I ran dig protonmail.com, which gave a correct ouput:
; <<>> DiG 9.18.28-1~deb12u2-Debian <<>> protonmail.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 12017
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;protonmail.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
protonmail.com.     1200    IN  A   185.70.42.12

;; Query time: 31 msec
;; SERVER: 213.186.33.99#53(213.186.33.99) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Thu Oct 10 17:32:34 UTC 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 59

Pinging protonmail.com also works. Any idea of a fix/workaround for that issue or where it might be coming from ? I want to be sure it doesn't come from a user error before opening an issue on github.
EDIT: it appears the container itself does not have access to the internet. I cannot ping a domain nor an IP address. Here is the docker compose I am using:
services:
  mailserver:
    image: ghcr.io/docker-mailserver/docker-mailserver:latest
    container_name: mailserver
    # Provide the FQDN of your mail server here (Your DNS MX record should point to this value)
    hostname: mail.$MY_DOMAIN.fr
    env_file: mailserver.env
    # More information about the mail-server ports:
    # https://docker-mailserver.github.io/docker-mailserver/latest/config/security/understanding-the-ports/
    ports:
      - "143:143"  # IMAP4 (explicit TLS => STARTTLS)
      - "465:465"  # ESMTP (implicit TLS)
      - "587:587"  # ESMTP (explicit TLS => STARTTLS)
      - "993:993"  # IMAP4 (implicit TLS)
      - "25:25"
    volumes:
      - ./docker-data/dms/mail-data/:/var/mail/
      - ./docker-data/dms/mail-state/:/var/mail-state/
      - ./docker-data/dms/mail-logs/:/var/log/mail/
      - ./docker-data/dms/config/:/tmp/docker-mailserver/
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /docker/vol/dms/cert:/var/cert
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    restart: always
    stop_grace_period: 1m
    healthcheck:
      test: "ss --listening --tcp | grep -P 'LISTEN.+:smtp' || exit 1"
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 0

I tried creating an external network and binding the service to it, didn't work.

I ran dig protonmail.com ... Pinging protonmail.com also works ... did you perform these tests from within the running docker container? Did you restart the docker container?

I did not run them from the container itself. I tried it just now, and it appears that the container does not have internet access. Editing the initial post now.
I did indeed restart the container as well as reboot the server multiple times.

it MUST have internet access to receive those emails ... it seems the DNS is not working ... e.g. ping 8.8.8.8 would work, ping google.com would not

Neither ping 8.8.8.8 nor ping google.com work.

weird, no outgoing connections at all, but emails still come in to be rejected

out of interest, remove the ports and replace with network_mode: host

Setting networkmode as host did the trick, thank you. Marking the issue as solved

By the way, I didn't suggest that as a solution. However, I can't recall what I was trying to determine 10 days ago by testing network_mode: host

Removing the ports block and setting network_mode to host did the trick as a workaround. Thanks to Jaromanda X.
